# htaccess redirect all requests from subfolder to subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, syntax

I have the following (WordPress) URL canonical structure:

`http://mysite.com/2011/10/my-post-name/`

I want to send all requests from `http://mysite.com/2011/...` down to the same location on a subdomain.

So specifically that should be:

`http://mysite.com/2011/10/my-post-name/` ---> `http://subdomain.mysite.com/2011/10/my-post-name/`

I'm not sure what the correct syntax is for this, does anyone know?

Comment: what is http://subdomain.mysite.com currently pointing to?

Comment: subdomain.mysite.com is on the same server, and is the new home for my blog.  Specifically, I need to send all requests for "http://dreamstarstudios.com/2011/..." to "http://blog.dreamstarstudios.com/2011/..."

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://subdomain.mysite.com$1 [R=301]
```

If you also need to match the first part of the path, then use

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^/2011/(.*) http://subdomain.mysite.com/2011/$1 [R=301]
```

You should read the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).  It's confusing the first time, but after the 25th time or so it will make pretty good sense and serve you well.

Comment: Can this be modified to look like this: 

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dreamstarstudios.com/2011/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://v3.dreamstarstudios.com/2011/$1 [R=301]`

Because, that's what I added to the htaccess and I'm not getting any redirecting happening...

Comment: No, that won't work because `%{HTTP_HOST}` only contains the site's host name, e.g. dreamstarstudios.com.  Other path components are matched and changed in the RewriteRule.

Comment: LOL.  You're right.  I'm just more of a front end developer, these kinds of intricate syntaxes always trip me up.  Question: will this work for only:

http://dreamstarstudios.com/2010/index.html

OR will it also work for:

http://dreamstarstudios.com/2010/10/my-post-name/

?  I'm sorry to give you a headache, but the rewrite still isn't taking place :/

Comment: Well as written above, it only works for /2011, not /2010.  If you want to write a more general rule that will do both, you really need to read the docs and learn about regular expressions.  Or, you could write two rules, one each for 2010 and 2011.

Comment: Right, as of right now, I just have 3 years worth of root URLs like that so I'm not worried about getting into regex for this.  The only purpose is to redirect stuff that is archived by Googlebot for SEO purposes, new posts will have the correct URL.  Anyway,  I have both 2010 & 2011 rewrite rules (that are identical except the number) in the htaccess and I'm getting nothing.